# Logging and Debugging using Maven within Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-surefire-plugin

As you may see in the screenshot an HBase testcase is being debugged.  We can also see the Run/Debug Configuration dialog and settings.

This particular Testcase configuration was generated by right-clicking on the testInitTableMapperConfigJob method and selecting "Debug testInitTableMapperConfigJob".  The result: amaven "Mvn" test target that uses the "test-compile surefire:test" plugin.

Here is the Run configuration command line;

test-compile surefire:test -Dtest=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapred.TestTableSnapshotInputFormat#testInitTableSnapshotMapperJobConfig -DforkMode=never -DforkCount=0

Two items I would like help with:

a) Why is the displayed breakpoint (in red) not being respected?
b)  Why none of the HBase logging messages and stdout/stderr for the testcase are not displayed (specifically the "Executing the testcase: .." message) on the console

[image]

Here is the test/resources/log4j.properties file: notice that the level is set to DEBUG for hadoop.hbase classes

```
hbase.root.logger=INFO,console
hbase.log.dir=.
hbase.log.file=hbase.log

# Define the root logger to the system property "hbase.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hbase.root.logger}

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshhold=ALL

#
# Daily Rolling File Appender
#
log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hbase.log.dir}/${hbase.log.file}

# Rollver at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# 30-day backup
#log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# Debugging Pattern format
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %C{2}(%L): %m%n


#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this
#
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %C{2}(%L): %m%n

# Custom Logging levels

#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSNamesystem=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase=DEBUG

#These two settings are workarounds against spurious logs from the minicluster.
#See HBASE-4709
log4j.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl=ERROR
log4j.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans=ERROR
# Enable this to get detailed connection error/retry logging.
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation=DEBUG
```

Comment: Put breakpoints earlier in the method, and single step through to the line you think you have your breakpoint on. See if the line you're interested in is actually executed.

Comment: @EngineerDollery   The screenshot partially displays the Console area that does print the message "Running o.a.s.m.TestTableSnapshotINputFormatInt". The code IS being run to completion, just no breakpoints or debug statements.

Answer (score 0):

mvn test wites logs to  /target/surefire-reports

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `-DforkMode=never`, or just use [Maven Helper plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179) to do it for you.

Comment: Hi, I updated the OP to show that already the -DforkMode=never -DforkCount=0 are included   (note it is "never" instead of "none")

Comment: This is a stock HBase testcase, not my own.  It runs and stops at the given breakpoint when run on command line with mvn in debug mode.